# Error trying to paginate through Twitter's search using codebird php

Tags: php, twitter, pagination

This is a very simple query and I must be doing something wrong, but am not seeing it right now.  I'm using codebird php library to connect and search Twitter.  I am able to find all friends/followers, create and destroy friendships, but for some reason am not paginating through a search of users correctly.

$cb is already connected and logged into twitter.

The problem that I'm having is that $u has the same list of users for each page.  In the end my $users array will have multiple copies of the first page for each loop and I cannot get more than 20 users from this search.  What is wrong with the query?

```
$count = 20; //max for users_search       
$type = 'q';
$total = 0;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    echo 'Page ' . $i . "\r\n";
    $u = $cb->users_search(array($type => $search, 'page' => $i, 'count' => $count));
    echo var_dump($u);
    $users[] = (array)$u;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$count = 20; //max for users_search    
$nbPage = 2; //2 pages for eg.
$type = 'q';
$search = '...';

for ($i = 1; $i <= $nbPage; $i++) {
    $params = array($type => $search, 'page' => $i, 'count' => $count); 
    $data = (array) $cb->users_search($params);
    for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
       $status = $data[$j];
       echo $status->name . " (@" . $status->screen_name . ")", '<br>';

    }
}
```